# Database Application Server connection association

Tags: db2, websphere, application-server, geronimo

I am having the following idea to investigate and find out if it possible to work. I am having a db2 server in a linux machine and two kinds of application servers, geronimo and websphere. I would like to know whether it is possible to associate a geronimo or websphere connection to a db2 agent.
In other words, I would like to know which user of a web application is running which query at the database at any given moment.
Thank you in advance,

Comment: It might be possible to use JDBC setClientInfo(). I don;t know what would be supported by your server, but this could be something to research: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fimjcc_t0052428.html

Comment: Also, in your SQL Reference, look for "CURRENT CLIENT..."

Answer (score 0):

You could create two users, one for Geronimo, and one for Websphere, both users in a same group. You give the privileges to the group, and both users will have the same privileges.

Then, when you issue a 'list applications' you could discriminate the connetions for Geronimo, and those for Websphere.

If you want to change the application name, there are two approaches depending the java connection.

**Class.forName**

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "scott");
props.put("password", "tiger");
props.put("clientProgramName", "My Program 1");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/sample", props);
```

**Datasource**

```
Connection conn = null;
DB2SimpleDataSource ds = new com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource();
ds.setDriverType(4);
ds.setServerName("localhost");
ds.setPortNumber(50000);
ds.setDatabaseName("sample");
ds.setUser("scott");
ds.setPassword("tiger");
ds.setClientProgramName("My Application 2");
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

You could assign the conneciont name dynamically, by retrieving the application server name.

I wrote a blog about that: http://angocadb2.blogspot.fr/2012/12/nombre-de-la-conexion-java-en-db2-java.html

Comment: My problem is not to distinct which connection comes from which server. I want to find out, clients on the same server, which db2 agent are using to perform their queries.

Comment: My problem is not to distinct which connection comes from which server. I want to find out, clients on the same server, which db2 agent are using to perform their queries. In stand alone this is easy as you mention. In an Application Server environment things get more complicated.

Comment: How do you differenciate each client on the server? If you could do that, you change the connection name to that value, and then you could differenciate each client on the server and in the database.

Comment: The easiest way with our setup is the ip address, since each server is running on different machine. Generally the idea is not to have both server, but either of them and wanted to know if in any of these two it's easier to find out what I am looking for.

Comment: You can know the origin of a connection, via db2 list applications in the 'Application Id' column, so the association is already done and you do not have to do anything. Sometimes the IP address is in hex a format.

Comment: Also, if DB2 is using connection concentrator, a single agent can process the requests from different application clients. If using *NIX, you can know what an agent is currently doing via db2top option a. Not available in Windows.

Comment: I am not interested in distinguishing users on different application servers. I am interested for the users that are connected to the same application server, either websphere of geronimo which agent are using at any given moment

Comment: What is 'user' for you? For me, a user is the one that connect to the database (application - a DBA perspective). But probably, you want to know the real users (people) (application perspective). Probably what you need is a trusted context: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0609mohan/

Comment: After some digging I found this as a more close solution to what I am looking for http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1208monitordbactivity/ . I 'll take a more thorough look and see if it suites my needs